# How to manage Instant App in new Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

Google recently launched new Google Play console beta.
https://play.google.com/console/

Is there Instant App management section available in new console?

In the old console it was available under `Release Management -> Instant App releases`

Comment: This section of the new Play Console is still in development.

Comment: This is still the case, you have to click on "Use classic Play Console" in the bottom of the play console menu to get to the old console, and publish it from there.

Comment: Is this still true? I uploaded app bundle to internal app sharing as well as Internal testing/Alpha track, but still my app links do not work. App links are good because they work if app is installed. So, I just need Google Play to tell me if there is a problem with my instant app setup.

Answer (score 2):

**Aug 2021**

*1-Time Setup:*  Go to Google Play Console > (your app) > Release (section) > Setup > Advanced Settings > Release Types (tab) > add "Google Play Instant"

*To Manage:* Go to Google Play Console > (your app) > Release (section) > Production > drop-down near upper right > Instant app only

From there you can upload Instant App AABs, manage your Instant App releases, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've spent hours trying to figure out why the store was ignoring my instant app updates! Google really hid this well! :-D