# Android Instant App URL execution trouble

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I've created what I think is an android instant app. When ever I test the instant app functionality via Android Studio it works as expected. I've followed the instructions to generate the associated files for linking the instant app to a URL and placed them accordingly on my site. I've uploaded a signed bundle to a alpha closed testing track. The URL I'm using will work to launch the app. However, when I goto Settings-> Google-> Apps & Notifications and remove the instant app, the link no longer works it takes me directly to the website. I dont understand what I've done wrong as its my understanding that instant apps dont need to be preinstalled the URL should trigger I assume the play store to send over a bundle to load into memory (of some sorts). Am I correct in thinking I should be able to run an instant app with out installing it first? Any help would be appreciated. Below is my manifest file. Which I believe to be correct.

Almost identical problem to: [InstantApp not being launched when clicking on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899984/instantapp-not-being-launched-when-clicking-on-link)

I've tried the solution mentioned in that post. To no success.

If this description/question sucks please let me know I will try to make it better. Second post ever first got deleted I presume because it sucked? No idea. Thanks community ahead of time for your help.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="learn.instantapps">
    
        <!-- The following declaration enables this module to be served instantly -->
        <dist:module dist:instant="true"></dist:module>
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    
            <activity android:name="learn.instantapps.MainActivity">
    
    
                <meta-data
                    android:name="default-url"
                    android:value="https://mysite/main" />
    
    
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:order="1">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="my site"
                        android:path="/main" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:order="1">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    
                    <data
                        android:scheme="http"
                        android:host="my site"
                        android:path="/main" />
                </intent-filter>
    
    
            </activity>
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```